# Items appearing together in a basket

Tags: python, pandas

I am completely stuck - I would like to count the number of cases an item appears together with another item in a basket, i.e. some correlation:

```
   basket item
0       a    x
1       a    y
2       a    z
3       b    x
4       b    y
5       c    k
6       c    y
7       c    z
8       d    x
9       d    y
10      d    z
11      d    l
```

That is, items `x`, `y`, and `z` appear together in basket `a`, items `x` and `y` appear together in basket `b`, etc.

I am looking for a way to get here:

```
    x   y   z   k   l
x       3   2       1
y   3       3   1   1
z   2   3       1   1
k       1   1       
l   1   1   1
```

The matrix is obviously symmetric. The first `3` in the top row  means, that `x` and `y` appear 3 times together in one basket (namely `a`, `b` and `d`), etc.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) by same DataFrame with `df`, then remove rows with same `item` values and last count combinations by [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html), last if need order of values like original add [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df1 = df.merge(df, on='basket')
i = df['item'].unique()
df1 = df1[df1.item_x != df1.item_y]
df2 = pd.crosstab(df1.item_x, df1.item_y).reindex(index=i, columns=i)

print (df2)
item_y  x  y  z  k  l
item_x               
x       0  3  2  0  1
y       3  0  3  1  1
z       2  3  0  1  1
k       0  1  1  0  0
l       1  1  1  0  0
```

If need missing values use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
df1 = df.merge(df, on='basket')
i = df['item'].unique()
df1 = df1[df1.item_x != df1.item_y]
df2 = df1.pivot_table(index='item_x', 
                      columns='item_y', 
                      aggfunc='size').reindex(index=i, columns=i)

print (df2)
item_y    x    y    z    k    l
item_x                         
x       NaN  3.0  2.0  NaN  1.0
y       3.0  NaN  3.0  1.0  1.0
z       2.0  3.0  NaN  1.0  1.0
k       NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN
l       1.0  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN
```